# PHP require() or include() and call a class variable?

Tags: php, class, include, require

I imagine this is fairly simple and one I should be able to get but I am having trouble with it. I can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere.

Consider the scenario: I have two files (we'll call them index.php and global.php). I am properly referencing the `require_once()` file.

Index.php:

```
<?php
require_once('./global.php');

$database = new database();
echo $database->dbname;
?>
```

Global.php:

```
<?php
class database {
public $dbname = 'jdoe';
}
?>
```

This does not output 'jdoe' on the index.php page. However...if I place the following into global.php, it works:

```
<?php
class database {
public $dbname = 'jdoe';
}

$database = new database();
echo $database->dbname;
?>
```

Comment: There are no errors...it is simply blank. That is an interesting point though.

Comment: That second one shouldn't work...

Comment: Oops...excuse me, let me fix that error in my post. That's not the problem though. [Try it now]

Comment: Also, are you sure you're including the correct file?  Try getcwd() to make sure your patch is correct.

Comment: I'm including the correct file...I have already tested this by echoing a variable outside of the class. This is all a condensed version of the actual files, but nothing else should be causing me problems. I should also note that this is my first attempt(s) at using classes.

Comment: Placing procedural code in the class withod a function wrapper should cause a fatal error. Are you sure that global.php is located at the same directory level as index.php?

Comment: In which version of php?

Comment: Correct: it is in the same level.

Comment: Actually question was for mgraphic. In which version of php adding procedural code to class is fatal error? I've used php till 5.2 and it wasn't the case.

Comment: Like I said, first global.php should and does work fine (tested). Put this at the top of index.php "ini_set('display_errors', 'on');" obviously without quotes. But you DO need parenthesis upon instantiating the class.

Comment: From what I understand, all versions. I don't think this is a valid syntax structure.

Comment: **Oh, duh...ha ha. I figured it out; sorry guys! It was another issue: I was referencing a function that doesn't exist (and I was using '@functionName()' to suppress errors. I wouldn't have figured that would have made a problem, but that was it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$database = new database();
```

You forgot the parenthesis. Also, take a look at the php documentation for [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) if you need more information about using classes in php.

**Update**:

Reading up on [PHP Class Properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) I came across this little tid-bit:

> [Class member variables] must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

I'm not 100% certain on this, but it seems like PHP is seeing your string assignment as "run-time information". Try assigning your variable in the constructor (its probably better practice anyway).

```
class database {
    public $dbname;
    function __construct() {
        $this->dbname= 'jdoe';
    }
    // Rest of class
}
```

Hope that helps! And if anyone could verify my assumption that would be great.

Comment: I have already tried using parenthesis...either way, same problem. And yes, I have been going through the PHP docs already.

Comment: There's no constructor, you don't need the (), even though they don't hurt.

Comment: True enough, PMV, thanks. I read up on properties [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) and may have a solution. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of making an object in php is

`$obj=new class();`

You have missed () after class name.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
$database = new database();
```

instead of

```
$database = new database;
```

Comment: I have already tried using parenthesis. This does not help/hinder.

Comment: I tried using your exact code with parenthesis, it works fine (the first global.php). Please see if you installed PHP that supports OOP? Or perhaps make sure you are actually importing the right file. Make sure you are not inhibiting any errors.

Comment: Ok, I will see if there is some other issue I am not seeing.